# Inline css extraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extract style applied on text "Hello World" in either javascript or jquery.

Suppose, for example, this is the html in which style is applied on "Hello World"

```
<div id="root" style="text-align: right;">
<span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract all style applied on "Hello World" by smarter way either in javascript or jquery.
Output should be all style that is **text-align: right;font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;**

How can I do this? Please tell anybody.

Regards

-------------Updated----------------------

Thank you all for yours valuable comments. But still I am not getting solution. I again want to more clarify problem statement with code.

Static html:

```
<div id="contentplaceholder">
</div>
```

After drag and drop the widget in place holder dynamic htmls is generated.

Dynamically generated html:

```
<div id="contentplaceholder">

<div style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0pt; top: 0pt;" title="textWidget" id="contTextarea1329455914127">
<div style="border: 1px dotted rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 150px; width: 300px; float: left; overflow: hidden; left: 561.033px; top: 166.5px; position: relative; display: block;" id="Textarea1329455914127" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable">

<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Now We can write any text like Hello World in dropped area and can apply style using provided widget toolbar.

Now final html is:

```
<div id="contentplaceholder">

    <div style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0pt; top: 0pt;" title="textWidget" id="contTextarea1329455914127">
    <div style="border: 1px dotted rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 150px; width: 300px; float: left; overflow: hidden; left: 561.033px; top: 166.5px; position: relative; display: block;" id="Textarea1329455914127" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable">

<!-- Dynamically applied inline css on Hello World and need to extract style only for this area-->
<!-- Start -->
<div style="text-align: right;">
<span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">HELLO WORLD</span>
<br>
</div>  
<!-- End -->  
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Now, I only want to extract style applied on "Hello World".
Here only root div is fixed and all child div with their id are dynamically generated and not fixed, only title is I am getting same like title="textWidget"

Kindly provide help to accomplish this task.

Regards

Comment: do you want to extract the data, or eliminate it?  What's the purpose of extracting it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://forum.jquery.com/topic/css-with-no-arguments-should-return-a-object-of-style-attributes

Answer (score 0):

$('#contentplaceholder span').first().attr('style') would return the style text in full.

I would suggest that you id the span and use that to reference the tag and only use this method if all you want to get is the text content of the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used this a couple of times and does the job .... will get style from both CSS files and Inline :

```
function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets,
        o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        };
    }
    return s;
}
```

Usage : `var style = css($("#element"));`

Comment: Thank you all for yours valuable comments. But still I am not getting solution. I again want to more clarify problem statement with code.

Comment: Thanks! but still not getting solution. Please find my updated post!!